# Android: Viewpager :: Swiping smoothly between tabs

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager

My Activity has a viewpager along with a tablayout. There are three tabs. Now while swiping between the tabs, there is noticeable delay (around 300ms) while i try to very quickly swipe from, say, the first to third tab.

Now the viewpager contains three fragments. I am using a FragmentPagerAdapter to declare the viewpager tabs (as this gave a slight improvement compared to when i used FragmentStatePagerAdapter). Also I have set offScreenPageLimit for the viewpager to 2 (since there are 3 tabs).

Now to find out what was going wrong, I initialised empty fragments for the tabs and the swiping was fine and smooth as expected.

Next, I implemented the full functional code for the middle/2nd tab and left the other two as empty fragment.

Now this is where things get interesting, I was expecting a small delay while i swipe **into** the middle fragment(it contains nothing but a listview), when it creates it views and plugs the adapter into the listview with data. However, that was not the case. There was a noticeable delay **while swiping out of the middle fragment!**

Thus I have reason to believe, that while swiping out, where the fragment's view is being removed from screen, there is something I need to take care of which will make the transition smoother.

Comment: http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/